# Compiling static libs of ffmpeg with x264 in Msys2 for Visual Studio, but libx264 is never found

Tags: ffmpeg, configure, msys2, libx264

Having previously downloaded and compiled ffmpeg 4.2.2 to static libraries using MSYS2 and the Visual Studio 2015 x64 tool chain. I want to add the x264 codec from VLC/VideoLan, compiling that to a static library as well. However, running Configure for ffmpeg produces an error saying "libx264 not found."

I built ffmpeg without VideoLAN's x264 at "/c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2" with "make install" installing to "/c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build" .

I am using the following steps to compile from source x264 and add it to the ffmpeg build using the same VS2015 tool chain:

1. Launch an "VS2015 x64 Natice Tools Command Prompt"
2. From that VS2015 command prompt, run "c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64 -use-full-path"
3. From inside the MSYS2 shell, run "cd /c/ThirdParty/opt"
4. git clone http://git.videolan.org/git/x264.git
5. cd x264
6. CC=cl ./configure --enable-static --prefix=/c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build --disable-cli
7. make
8. make install
9. cd ../ffmpeg-4.2.2
10. PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build/lib \
    ./configure --prefix=./ffmpeg_build --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86_64 \
    --target-os=win64 --extra-cflags=-MT --extra-cxxflags=-MT \
    --extra-ldflags=-L/c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build/lib \
    --enable-x86asm --enable-asm --enable-static --disable-shared \
    --disable-debug --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libx264

The steps work, compiling x264 fine, but the output for ffmpeg's Configure is "ERROR: libx264 not found".

I have also tried the variation of using these two lines in place of steps 6 and 10 above:

- CC=cl ./configure --enable-static --prefix=/usr/local --disable-cli
- PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH ./configure --prefix=./ffmpeg_build --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86_64 --target-os=win64 --extra-cflags=-MT  --extra-libs=/usr/local/lib/libx264.lib --extra-cxxflags=-MT --enable-x86asm --enable-asm --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libx264

This version will get past Configure, where I am able to run "make", but the make fails with a series of unresolved X264_* functions while linking ffmpeg_g.exe, 14 unresolved functions in total. The errors at shown at the bottom, but first:

When I look in /c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build/lib I see:

```
$ ls -l ./ffmpeg_build/lib
total 50988
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 27184250 May 11 16:29 libavcodec.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake   231304 May 11 16:29 libavdevice.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake  8574628 May 11 16:29 libavfilter.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake  8081930 May 11 16:29 libavformat.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake  1300118 May 11 16:29 libavutil.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake    61844 May 11 16:29 libpostproc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake   348732 May 11 16:29 libswresample.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake  1316008 May 11 16:29 libswscale.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake  5086976 May 28 18:08 libx264.lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 blake blake        0 May 28 18:08 pkgconfig
```

Likewise for /c/ThirdParty/opt/ffmpeg-4.2.2/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig:

```
$ ls -l ./ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig/
total 9
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 353 May 11 16:29 libavcodec.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 554 May 11 16:29 libavdevice.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 449 May 11 16:29 libavfilter.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 393 May 11 16:29 libavformat.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 306 May 11 16:29 libavutil.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 317 May 11 16:29 libpostproc.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 322 May 11 16:29 libswresample.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 315 May 11 16:29 libswscale.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 blake blake 300 May 28 18:08 x264.pc
```

And looking in /usr/local/lib I see libx264.lib and the pkgconfig directory.

The errors generated by my most recent attempts look like:

```
LD      ffmpeg_g.exe
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_param_default referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_param_parse referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_param_default_preset referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_param_apply_profile referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_picture_init referenced in function X264_frame
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_open_160 referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_reconfig referenced in function reconfig_encoder
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_headers referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_encode referenced in function X264_frame
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_close referenced in function X264_close
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_delayed_frames referenced in function X264_frame
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_encoder_maximum_delayed_frames referenced in function X264_init
libavcodec.a(libx264.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_x264_levels referenced in function X264_init
ffmpeg_g.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
make: *** [Makefile:111: ffmpeg_g.exe] Error 96
```

Maybe something wrong with the --extra-ldflags or --extra-libs options of ffmpeg's Configure, but after trying variations and google searching, **I come asking you.** Do you know what is wrong with this ffmpeg Configure line? Step 10, above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment or remove this lines in libavcodec\libx264.c:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define X264_API_IMPORTS 1
#endif
```

This probably should help with your `unresolved external symbol` errors.
As for errors with original item 10 than you set wrong value for PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing to lib dir instead of pkgconfig dir.